# MongoDB Aggregation Pipeline - get oldest document, but debounced

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, nosql-aggregation

I have documents that look like:

```json
[ 
  { 
    value: 'Apple',
    createdAt: '2021-12-09T20:15:26.421+00:00',
  },
  { 
    value: 'Blueberry',
    createdAt: '2021-12-09T20:45:26.421+00:00',
  },
  { 
    value: 'Cranberry',
    createdAt: '2021-12-09T21:30:26.421+00:00',
  },
  { 
    value: 'Durian',
    createdAt: '2022-01-24T20:15:26.421+00:00',
  },
  { 
    value: 'Elderberry',
    createdAt: '2022-01-24T20:45:26.421+00:00',
  },
]
```

I'd like to do an aggregation where I get the oldest document, with the caveat that if another document was created within an hour, it invalidates the first document and I actually want to grab that one instead. For example, in the above I would like to return `Cranberry`. Initially pick `Apple`, but since `Blueberry` comes within an hour, move to that one, and since `Cranberry` comes within an hour of `Blueberry`, select `Cranberry`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the followings in an aggregation pipeline:

1. `$sort` by `createdAt`
2. `$limit` to get the oldest document
3. `$lookup` to get all the documents with `createdAt` behind the current document
4. `$reduce` to loop the result array; update the accumulator/result only if the current entry is within 1 hour

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $sort: {
      createdAt: 1
    }
  },
  {
    $limit: 1
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "collection",
      let: {
        current: "$createdAt"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $gte: [
                "$createdAt",
                "$$current"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "within"
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "within": {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": "$within",
          "initialValue": null,
          "in": {
            "$cond": {
              "if": {
                $or: [
                  {
                    $eq: [
                      "$$value",
                      null
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    $lte: [
                      {
                        "$subtract": [
                          "$$this.createdAt",
                          "$$value.createdAt"
                        ]
                      },
                      3600000
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              },
              "then": "$$this",
              "else": "$$value"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/56FSI72hdcL) for your reference.